# Movie Theater Website - Wordpress - Pull in Fandango Showtimes

Tags: wordpress, scrape

I am new to coding and need this all dumbed down for me. Any suggestions would be great. I own a movie theater. I built a website using Wordpress to display our showtimes. I used a template that I bought on themeforest. The URL is http://www.uptown3theatre.com

Right now I have to manually add movies and showtimes data daily. Our Point of Sale at the theater allows me to schedule our movies, and then it automatically adds the films to Fandango.

I am hoping someone can help me display these showtimes automatically by either linking in with an API(which I am struggling with) or by scraping the data in.(none of the scraper plugins are working quite right)

Alternatively there is an online ticketing platform that we could scrape from. That URL is https://ticketing.useast.veezi.com/sessions/?siteToken=pxbww48zebzhba4e6yzr7f01am

Either of these solutions would possibly work.

The caveat is that I only want to display the showtime information. I do not want to link to ticket purchase pages for either. Atleast for right now.

I am stuck and found myself looking over many blogs, but am not able to make much sense, or I don't yet have the technical skills to implement what they are suggesting.

Any help or pointing in the right direction would be great! Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: @NicoHaase I have tried using several scraping tools. Such as Scrape Storm and then also the Wordpress scraper WP Scrape. The problem with these is that they can't load the webpages correctly because of the languages they use. And the info it does pull in unfortunately doesn't display correctly on my pages, most likely due to CSS of the theme.

Comment: @NicoHaase I have also tried using an IFrame, but the webpages have ads and links to other local theaters listed on the page specifically. I have done some research to see if I could use an IFrame and only pull in the XPath I want, but got nowhere there either.

Comment: How is the API data returned?  I would go with the API, so you can format how you want.